# Converting href attribute from Aura to LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, aura, html

I have this code in my aura and I tried it to convert it to LWC.

Aura:

```
<a href="{!v.urlRecord.Link__c + '?tag=' + v.urlRecord.Tag__c}" target="_blank" class="alert-link">{!v.urlRecord.Link__c + '?tag=' + v.urlRecord.Tag__c}</a>
```

What I did in LWC is this:

HTML:

```
<a href={linkGen} target="_blank" class="alert-link">{linkGen}</a>
```

JS:

```
connectedCallback() {
    getUrl({communityName:this.communityName}).then(response => {
        this.urlRecord= response;
        this.linkGen= this.urlRecord.Link__c + '?tag=' + this.urlRecord.Tag__c;
        
    });
}
```

Apex:

```
public with sharing class GetUrlController {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Url__c fetchUrlRecord(string communityName) {
    
    Url__c getUrl;
    
    for(Url__c cUrl:[SELECT Id, Link__c, Tag__c, Active__c, Community_To_Alert_On__c, Start_Time__c, End_Time__c  
                           FROM Url__c
                           WHERE Active__c = true and Community_To_Alert_On__c includes (:communityName)
                           ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC])
    {
        if(cUrl.Start_Time__c <= System.Now() &&
           cUrl.End_Time__c > System.Now())
        {
            getUrl = cUrl;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    return getUrl;
}
```

}

But as expected, it didn't work. Anyone knows what wrong in the code. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the imperative apex you are calling, so we can see the response structure.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the Apex. Done adding it to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are invoking the getUrl function directly in `connectedCallback()`, your `this` context refers to anything declared within this function.

Try this:

```
connectedCallback(){
  this.callGetUrl(this.communityName);
}

callGetUrl=(communityName)=>{
  getUrl({communityName})
    .then(response => {
      this.urlRecord= response;
      this.linkGen= this.urlRecord.Link__c + '?tag=' + this.urlRecord.Tag__c;
    }
  });
}
```

You could also make `connectedCallback` an arrow function to remove it's `this` context, but it seems cleaner this way.

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you suggest and it works.